# form with ajax dosen't send values

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a custom form built that generates some fields based on a select box, 
the form works ok on user side. it loads new rooms when select changes.
the problem is that the globallink_ui_search_hotels in form[values]['hotels']['rooms'] it will only show room_0 even if you select 2 or more rooms.

update:
 from what i can see the after number of rooms changes, the generated select boxes dose not have a name attribute

```
  function globallink_ui_search_form($form, &$form_submit){ // the form creation function
  //........
  $form['hotels']['nrrooms'] = array(
      '#multiple_toggle' => '1',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title'=>t('Number of rooms'),
      '#options' => array(
        1=>1,
        2=>2,
        3=>3,
        4=>4,
        5=>5,
        6=>6,
        ),
      '#default_value'=>1,
      '#ajax'=>array(
        'callback'=>'globallink_ui_rooms_change_callback',
        'wrapper'=>'globallink-ui-rooms-change-wrapper',
        'effect' => 'slide',
        ),
      // '#title' => t('select departing time'),
    );

    globallink_ui_rooms_change_callback($form,$form_state);

  //....
    $form['hotels']['submit'] = array(
      '#weight' => '7',
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('FIND HOTELS'),
      '#submit' => array('globallink_ui_search_hotels')
    );

  }

  function globallink_ui_rooms_change_callback(&$form,&$form_state){

    $nradults=array();
    for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++) { 
      $nradults[$i] = $i;
    }


     $form['hotels']['rooms'] = array(
        '#collapsed' => '0',
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#collapsible' => '0',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="globallink-ui-rooms-change-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $nrrooms=!empty($form_state['values']) ? $form_state['values']['hotels']['nrrooms'] : 1;

    for($i = 0 ; $i<$nrrooms;$i++){

      $form['hotels']['rooms']['room_'.$i] = array(      
          '#weight' => $i,
          '#title'=>'Room '.($i+1),
          '#collapsed' => '0',
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#collapsible' => '0',
      );

      $form['hotels']['rooms']['room_'.$i]['adults'] = array(
        '#required' => '1',
        '#default_value' => 1,     
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title'=>'Adults',
        '#options' => $nradults,
      );

      $form['hotels']['rooms']['room_'.$i]['infants'] = array(
        '#required' => '1',
        '#default_value' => 1,
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title'=>'Infants',
        '#options' => $nradults,
      );
    }

    return $form['hotels']['rooms'];
  }

  function globallink_ui_search_hotels($form, &$form_state){
    dpm($form_state['values'],'search hotels');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place

```
 $form['hotels']['rooms'] = array(
    '#collapsed' => '0',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#collapsible' => '0',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="globallink-ui-rooms-change-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

in globallink_ui_search_form function. The wrapper tag must be loaded before callback send.

Comment: i did that and i have the same result

Comment: @Tica if I understand what QQQ is saying, you should never put anything that's meant to be persistent in a callback function. You must remember that form is essentially (working simplification) rebuilt at each request. So if the form element will not be added on the form build triggered by submit request, Drupal will treat it as non-existent and ignore it's values. You need to store in `$form_state` or similar place which fields are to be added, not just add them on a button click. I know it's a bit counter-intuitive, but that's the beauty of stateless HTTP protocol.